# YouTube full of people which smoke their ears vs YouTube is filled with people etc?

Tags: word-request

I'm looking for the suitable word for the following context:

> 1. YouTube **full of** people which smoke through their ears
> 2. YouTube is **filled with** peoplewhich smoke through their ears

Answer (score 1):

> YouTube is **filled with/full of** people *who* smoke through their ears.

You would use *who* since it refers to people. Beyond that, I don't see any real difference here between *filled with* and *full of*.

A small point, but it would be more precise to say:

> YouTube is filled with/full of **videos** of people *who* smoke through their ears.

since YouTube really isn't full of people...